# socket error while closing the connection,how to solve it?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to run client serevr socket but ia m getting the below error
client code

```
enter code here

#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket
HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 65432        # The port used by the server

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
d=input("enter numbers")
f=input("enter numbers")
val = str(d)  # sep = ' ' or sep = `\n`
s.send(val)
val1 = str(f) # sep = ' ' or sep = `\n`
s.send(val1)



#s.send(d)
#s.send(f)
data = s.recv(1024)
data5=int(data)

print('Received', repr(data5))
s.close()


server

#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket

 HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 65432        # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(PORT)
conn, addr = s.accept()
with conn:
       print('Connected by', addr)
       while True:
            w1 = conn.recv(1024)
            w2= conn.recv(1024)

     #w1=int(w[0])
         #w2=int(w[1])       
            data3=w1-w2
            data3=str(data3)
            if not data:
               break
            conn.sendall(data3)
conn.close()
```

error-socket.error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
I am facing this error,can we resolve this , i guess here we have an issue with tcp connection closed too soon.